# Chef: Node object gets created after node DELETE

Tags: chef-infra

I'm seeing a very strange behavior, which happens very sporadically -

After running

```
knife node delete NODE_NAME
```

The node is indeed deleted but then for 'some reason' i'm seeing on the Chef server a `PUT` request that creates the node again

Logs

Node deleted

```
2018-02-08T09:00:06Z erchef@127.0.0.1 method=DELETE; path=/organizations/MYORG/nodes/NODE_NAME; status=200; req_id=g3IAA2QAEGVyY2hlZkAxMjcuMC4wLjECAABZyT0QAAEAAAAA; org_name=MYORG; couchdb_groups=false; couchdb_organizations=false; couchdb_containers=false; couchdb_acls=false; 503_mode=false; couchdb_associations=false; couchdb_association_requests=false; req_time=19; rdbms_time=4; rdbms_count=4; authz_time=4; authz_count=1; user=NODE_NAME; req_api_version=1
```

In between I'm seeing some `GET` and `POST` requests containing the NODE_NAME not sure if this has any significance.

`2018-02-08T09:00:06Z erchef@127.0.0.1 method=GET; path=/organizations/MYORG/nodes/NODE_NAME; status=404; req_id=g3IAA2QAEGVyY2hlZkAxMjcuMC4wLjECAABZ5z0QAAEAAAAA; org_name=MYORG; msg=node_not_found; couchdb_groups=false; couchdb_organizations=false; couchdb_containers=false; couchdb_acls=false; 503_mode=false; couchdb_associations=false; couchdb_association_requests=false; req_time=3; rdbms_time=0; rdbms_count=3; user=NODE_NAME; req_api_version=1;
2018-02-08T09:00:06Z erchef@127.0.0.1 method=POST; path=/organizations/MYORG/nodes; status=201; req_id=g3IAA2QAEGVyY2hlZkAxMjcuMC4wLjECAABaAT0QAAEAAAAA; org_name=MYORG; msg={created,<<"NODE_NAME">>}; couchdb_groups=false; couchdb_organizations=false; couchdb_containers=false; couchdb_acls=false; 503_mode=false; couchdb_associations=false; couchdb_association_requests=false; req_time=63; rdbms_time=2; rdbms_count=4; user=NODE_NAME; req_api_version=1;
2018-02-08T09:00:07Z erchef@127.0.0.1 method=POST; path=/organizations/MYORG/environments/_default/cookbook_versions; status=200; req_id=g3IAA2QAEGVyY2hlZkAxMjcuMC4wLjECAAD6IjugAAIAAAAA; org_name=MYORG; couchdb_groups=false; couchdb_organizations=false; couchdb_containers=false; couchdb_acls=false; 503_mode=false; couchdb_associations=false; couchdb_association_requests=false; req_time=28; rdbms_time=14; rdbms_count=5; authz_time=9; authz_count=3; depsolver_time=0; depsolver_count=1; user=NODE_NAME; req_api_version=1;`

Node re-created apparently

```
2018-02-08T09:00:07Z erchef@127.0.0.1 method=PUT; path=/organizations/MYORG/nodes/NODE_NAME; status=200; req_id=g3IAA2QAEGVyY2hlZkAxMjcuMC4wLjECAABa2j0QAAEAAAAA; org_name=MYORG; couchdb_groups=false; couchdb_organizations=false; couchdb_containers=false; couchdb_acls=false; 503_mode=false; couchdb_associations=false; couchdb_association_requests=false; req_time=80; rdbms_time=7; rdbms_count=4; authz_time=2; authz_count=1;
```

So my question does the Chef server have any re-create mechanism of a node object under certain circumstances AFTER the node has been explicitly been deleted ?

Thanks everyone for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Chef in some kind of interval mode (either our own daemon-mode support or a cron job or whatever), and there was an active converge in progress when you did the delete, when the node saves itself up to Chef Server at the end of the converge, it would come back. Always make sure you terminate any active converges before modiyfing a node (same thing happens with edits in addition to deletes). That said, if you also remove the client at the same time, the save would try to happen, but fail with an authentication error.